# override pinMode, digitalWrite and digitalRead

Tags: linker, io-expander

I am using the [ESP32 Arduino Framework](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32) and I have some [GPIO expanders](https://www.ti.com/product/TCA6408A) attached via I²C. They work fine and I now want to map some unused pin numbers to them so I can used my custom pin numbers in `pinMode`, `digitalRead` and `digitalWrite`.

Luckily, [the Arduino core links these functions weakly](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-gpio.c#L228).

```cpp
extern void pinMode(uint8_t pin, uint8_t mode) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("__pinMode")));
```

I defined my own functions like so:

```cpp
void pinMode(uint8_t pin, uint8_t mode) {
    if(pin<0x80)
        // call conventional handler
    else
        // communicate with GPIO expander via I²C
}
```

Unfortunately, calling any of the functions will not result in the linker picking my implementation but the linker picks the default implementation.

Any ideas how to override the weakly linked `pinMode`, `digitalWrite` and `digitalRead`?

Comment: use a different parameter type. some `struct MyPin {int pin;}` create constants like MP0, MP1,..

Comment: It used overloading before and it works for my custom code. However, I want all 3rd party libraries and the Arduino core to call my functions. E.g. when a display library call `digitalWrite` on some pins, I want that to work even if that GPIO is on my GPIO expander. Overloading would require me to rewrite the Arduino core and 3rd party libraries to use my function instead. I want to avoid that.

Comment: there are very few uses of these functions in core (analogWrite, tone, shift). with which libraries you want to use the io expander?

Comment: E.g. in [MD_AD9833](https://registry.platformio.org/libraries/majicdesigns/MD_AD9833). My project will a tons of peripherals attached so I would have to fork many different libraries. That would not be viable...

Comment: that library uses SPI. do you need to run the CS pin over io expander? most libraries use SPI, I2C, PWM or direct register manipulation

Comment: You are exactly right. I need to run the CS pin over an SPI expander. In fact, my project has five different CS signals attached to IO expanders in addition to the native GPIOs of the ESP32. The other GPIOs on the expanders are used for relays and MOSFETs so I could address them with an overloaded function as you proposed. But the five CS pins are addressed by some thrid party libraries using the builtin `digitalWrite`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue: I ran `platformio run --target clean` instead of `platformio run --target cleanall`. It seems that only the latter command cleans all build artifacts. The next time I compiled and uploaded, it worked as expected.

Another issue occurs only with Adafruit libraries: Some libraries do not use `uint8_t` for ports but `int8_t` and they do checks like

```cpp
if(pin_number >=0)  {
    // code that only works with pin numbers between 0x01 and 0x80
}
```

Take the [Adafruit GFX library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GFX-Library/blob/5ea4be3ffeae918899aeec8cbb67f87359cf0026/Adafruit_SPITFT.cpp#L533) as an example. As a workaround, I will map my GPIO expander ports to 0x40, 0x41, ...